# Where can I find the link icon in Polarion?

Tags: polarion

I read the [tutorials](http://reqdemo.polarion.com) of the demoversion of the [*Polarion REQUIREMENTS*](https://www.polarion.com/products/polarion-requirements) software. On the page *How to link*, one can read the following:
[image]
However, I cannot find the link icon. Where is it or why can I not see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing a sidebar might help.

For example: the *Approvals* sidebar replaces the link symbol in front of a requirement by other symbols.
[image]